# Embed Pyqtgraph into Pyqt Textedit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph, qtextedit

I'd like to create a text editor where you can drag and drop Pyqtgraphs and interact with them real-time. I am having trouble understanding the behavior of TextEdit and how a Widget could be 'embedded' within the TextEdit itself. After review the API it seems that only text, html, and images can be added into the QTextEdit.

I might be grasping at straws here, but I was hoping that there was a `void QTextEdit::insertWidget(QWidget*)` or something of that nature.

To clarify here is an incomplete sample code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import pyqtgraph as pg


class PlotTextEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)

        toolbar = QToolBar()

        plotAction = QAction('Plot', self)
        plotAction.triggered.connect(self.addPlot)
        toolbar.addAction(plotAction)

        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        self.setGeometry(300, 100, 800, 1000)

    def addPlot(self):
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        y = np.sin(x)

        glWidget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        plot = glWidget.addPlot()
        plot.plot(x, y, pen='r')

        # I'd like to be able to use a line such as this
        # self.textEdit.textCursor().insertWidget(glWidget)
        self.textEdit.textCursor().insertText('I want to insert a widget pointer instead.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    pte = PlotTextEditor()
    pte.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Some ideas I had were to overlay the pyqtgraph over a blank image, or try to find some kind of text widget I can insert and override paintevent to give it the pyqtgraph paint. Ultimately however, I am not sure if this is even possible with the current Qt backend with TextEdit.

Comment: I updated , please look my answer.

Comment: @user9402680 Thank you. I'll need some time to digest all the code, but it has the functionality I want.

Comment: If you have a difficult point to understand, please don't hesitate to ask me about it by comment or new question. If probably, it may be a new question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this Code.

If you want to further information , please ask me by comment.
I don't know if you like this result or not.

**UPDATE TRANSITION**

1. plot image can be rendered but the data is not rendered.
   I changed `pen = 'r': plot.plot(x, y, pen)` to `plot.plot(x, y, pen = 'r')`
2. the data of plot image is dirty and not antialiased, intercepted on and off.
   I update `intrinsicSize()` and return image width and image height,
   You can look a bad result if you set `return QSizeF()` argument in    `intrinsicSize` as you like.
3. Interactively as possible as we can.
   As you can see, this image is drawn by `QPainter`. So , originally, this is uninteractive.I think this is the only way for rendering your result as `QTextObject`. `QTextEdit` can't accept a kind of widgets as text.
4. Please click in front of the image.
   `GraphicsLayoutWidget` shows.and you change the graph contents, and you close it. And the next time, the image is redrawn and rendered again.
5. I deleted needless code.

Anyway, I tried to do until this point.

Please ask me about further imformation by comment.

```
import sys
import numpy as np

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters

import os
plot_image_dict = {}
class PlotObjectInterface(QObject, QTextObjectInterface):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PlotObjectInterface, self).__init__(parent=None)
    def drawObject(self, painter, rect, doc, posInDocument, format):      
        img = format.property(1)
        painter.save()        
        painter.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.drawImage(QRectF(rect), img)
        painter.restore()
    def intrinsicSize(self, doc, posInDocument, format):
        img = format.property(1)
        width = img.size().width()
        height = img.size().height()
        return QSizeF(width, height)

class PlotTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
class PlotView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.plot_scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.plot_tedit = PlotTextEdit()
        self.plot_tedit.resize(800, 1000)
        self.plot_scene.addWidget(self.plot_tedit)
        self.setScene(self.plot_scene)
class PlotGraphicsLayoutWidget(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
        self.current_edit_filename = ""
        self.current_edit_imagenum = 0
        self.current_edit_image = QImage()
        self.current_edit_position = 0
    def updateImage(self):
        #overwrite the image
        pg.QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
        exporter = pg.exporters.ImageExporter(self.scene())
        filename = os.path.join(self.current_edit_filename)
        exporter.export(filename)     
        image = QImage()
        image.load(filename)
        image_info = plot_image_dict[self.current_edit_imagenum]  
        tc = QTextCursor(self.current_text_edit.document())
        tc.setPosition(image_info[3] - 1, tc.MoveAnchor)
        tc.movePosition(tc.Right, tc.KeepAnchor, 1)
        tc.setKeepPositionOnInsert(True)
        char = QTextCharFormat()
        char.setObjectType(QTextFormat.UserObject + 1)              
        char.setProperty(1, image)
        char.setProperty(2, image_info[1])
        char.setProperty(3, image_info[2])
        char.setProperty(4, image_info[3])        
        plot_image_dict[self.current_edit_imagenum] = [image, image_info[1], image_info[2], image_info[3]]
        tc.insertText("\ufffc", char)
        tc.setKeepPositionOnInsert(False)
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.updateImage()
        return pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget.closeEvent(self, event)
class PlotTextEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.plotview = PlotView()
        self.pyplotObjectInterface = PlotObjectInterface()
        self.plotview.plot_tedit.document().documentLayout().registerHandler(QTextFormat.UserObject+1,self.pyplotObjectInterface)    
        self.plotview.plot_tedit.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.plotview)
        toolbar = QToolBar()
        plotAction = QAction('Plot', self)
        plotAction.triggered.connect(self.insertImage)
        toolbar.addAction(plotAction)
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)
        self.setGeometry(300, 100, 800, 1000)    
        self.test_glWidget = PlotGraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.test_glWidget.current_text_edit = self.plotview.plot_tedit

        self.test_manipulation = False
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        y = np.sin(x)               
        plot = self.test_glWidget.addPlot()       
        #PlotDataItem
        plot.plot(x, y, pen = 'b')
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        QApplication.closeAllWindows()
        return QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, event)
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):    
        if event.type() == QMouseEvent.MouseButtonPress and  obj == self.plotview.plot_tedit.viewport():
            tc = self.plotview.plot_tedit.textCursor()
            position = tc.position()
            tc.movePosition(tc.Left, tc.KeepAnchor,1)
            if tc.selectedText() == "\ufffc":                
                self.editImage(tc)                            
            tc.clearSelection()
            tc.setPosition(position)            
            p_next = position + 1
            tc.setPosition(p_next, tc.KeepAnchor)
            if tc.selectedText() == "\ufffc":
                print("next character is \ufffc")
                tc.clearSelection()
                self.editImage(tc)                  
            return False
        return QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
    def editImage(self, tc):        
        tc = QTextCursor(tc)
        rect = self.plotview.plot_tedit.cursorRect(tc)
        topLeft = rect.topLeft()
        child_topLeft = self.plotview.mapToGlobal(topLeft)
        char = tc.charFormat()
        plot_img =  char.property(1)
        plot_num = char.property(2)
        filename = char.property(3)
        char.setProperty(4, tc.position())
        if plot_img  is not None:                    
            geometry = QRect(topLeft,QSize(plot_img .width(), plot_img .height()))
            self.test_glWidget.current_edit_filename = filename
            self.test_glWidget.current_edit_imagenum = plot_num
            self.test_glWidget.current_edit_image = plot_img
            self.test_glWidget.current_edit_position = tc.position()
            plot_image_dict[self.test_glWidget.current_edit_imagenum] = [plot_img, plot_num, filename,  tc.position()]
            self.test_glWidget.setGeometry(geometry)
            self.test_glWidget.show()    
    def insertImage(self):        
        pg.QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
        exporter = pg.exporters.ImageExporter(self.test_glWidget.scene())
        filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "plot.png")
        exporter.export(filename)
        plot_img = QImage()
        plot_img.load(filename)        
        plot_num = len(plot_image_dict)
        plot_char = QTextCharFormat()
        plot_char.setObjectType(QTextFormat.UserObject+1)        
        plot_char.setProperty(1, plot_img)     
        plot_char.setProperty(2, plot_num)
        plot_char.setProperty(3, filename)        
        plot_char.setProperty(4, 0)
        self.plotview.plot_tedit.textCursor().insertText("\ufffc", plot_char)
        plot_image_dict[plot_num] = [plot_img, plot_num, filename, 0]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    pte = PlotTextEditor()
    pte.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey I appreciate the effort to write this, but the actual plot data doesn't show up. Was this intentional?

Comment: @Michael Choi It happens because I wrote `pen = 'r'` out of the `plot.plot(x, y, pen)`.I didn't think of the reason, so I stuck for a while.I'm sorry.